# Megamenu desplegable no me funciona en móvil correctamente

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Tengo un megamenú desplegable, el problema es que el desplegable se hace mediante un `:hover`, y este `:hover` se fastidia a veces en móvil.

Con safari me va bien, pero a veces en chrome móvil no me detecta bien el touch en el elemento del menú, y simplemente me lo colorea con el `hover` pero no me despliega el menú.

El menú es este: https://megastar.es/

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: En móvil no existe hover, no tienes ratón.

Comment: @blonfu eso es mentira! Y si no te lo crees pruébalo tu mismo ;)

Comment: bien es cierto que en movil puedes usar raton... pero en las webs de movil hay hover?

Comment: Antonio, he visitado tu página y funciona correctamente, de todos modos te recomiendo que compartas el código fuente de esa parte en concreto por si se te ha pasado algo por alto y haga que no funcione correctamente en algunos navegadores.

Comment: @Javi he podido equivocarme pero si no es así podías dar referencias o explicar por qué. Diciendo que miento no arreglamos nada

Comment: Se puede simular el hover, pero en principio sin nada más que un :hover en CSS no funciona con los dedos, no puedes poner nada encima sin pulsar

Comment: Yo simplemente busco más precisión cuando el usuario toca el menú, quiero que se despliegue sí o sí en cuanto el usuario pulsa en el item del menú, por ejemplo en "experiencias", no quiero que se quede simplemente en un hover. También he añadido focus pero nada...